# Eventual problems getting response in mobile clients after doing insert from azure mobile service

Tags: android, azure, request, response, azure-mobile-services

I have an app that runs on android mobile smartphones and connects to azure mobile service backend (based on node js). Basically what I do is insert data to a table in the mobile service database. In the mobile app, after inserting my object I check if the response object has an id different to null, in that case I delete the row in the local sqlite database, if id equals "null" then I retry the operation later. The problem is that frequently I don't receive the id, so that id="null" and I retry operation, nevertheless when fetching the azure database the row was successfully inserted.

Here is part of my code:

```
    if (downeventstable == null && !error)
    downeventstable = FirstmenuScreen.mClient.getTable("downevents" + servicio, downevents.class); 

boolean error2 = true;

try {
    downeventstable.insert(dwnevent).get();
    error2=false;
        } catch (Exception e) {                   
                 error2 = true;
                  break; 
                    }


if (!error2 && dwnevent.getId() != null) {
                        // if no error and id was received deletes row locally in sqlite
                    }
```

I guess that the problem is caused by a bad quality of the mobile network, maybe the app lost connection after a successfull insertion in azure and didn't get the response object. How may I know if the data was inserted in azure and treat these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your insert was successful and you try to re-insert the same record with the same ID later, you'll get a 409 conflict. You can handle this in your sync conflict handler if you're using offline sync, or just exception handling if you're using a regular table.

Here's a [Xamarin sample that handles the 409 conflict](https://github.com/lindydonna/xamarin-forms-offline-sync/blob/master/XamarinFormsOffline/SyncHandler.cs#L32), which is `MobileServiceConflictException` in C#. You would do something similar in Java.  You can test this out by using a REST client and seeing that you get a 409.

Btw, it sounds like you are doing a lot of manual work with your own SQLite tables. You might want to consider using the offline sync feature that is built in, which will do the retries for you: [Add Offline Data Sync to your Android Mobile Services app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-offline-data/).

Note that Mobile Services is being deprecated, so we recommend that you upgrade your code to Mobile Apps if it is a new app. See [Announcing Azure Mobile Services transition to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transition-of-azure-mobile-services/).

Comment: Thanks, indeed I am doing the table sync manually using regular tables, It´s nice to hear about offline sync feature! I´m not getting 409 result code since the row ID is defined by azure backend (default ID generator script), perhaps It is a good idea setting the ID in the app so that record is rejected when ID is duplicated.